# Laravel Login Issue - Session Cookies Not Passed?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, session-cookies, session-state

First - coming back to this project - never saw this issue before so asking if anybody else has - when I set the project down it was working perfectly.  Additionally - several other projects on the same server using the same setup are working flawlessly.

So problem is this.
I login, the login is valid (I'm using DirectoryTree/Laravel to authenticate against LDAP, and have logs showing authentication was successful.  All other projects are also using DirectoryTree/Laravel - and since the login is processing I cant see this being the root cause).

I'm immediately redirected back to the / (correct behavior) - but the login form returns instead of loading the vue components when auth:check = true.

I can hard refresh the page - and suddenly I'm logged in.  (Must clear cache hard refresh at the browser) same action whether on Firefox, Chrome, Edge.  The log in is processed - but its like the session isnt being updated.

I'm using the normal login form with the ui:auth setup.

Anybody ever seen this?

Comment: When the `/` page loads, is ti https or http? Session cookies are generally only sent via secure connections so loading an http page will not send those cookies to the server.

Comment: The page is on https (self signed cert as in development server) Once again never saw this issue before.  The login goes via https - the return is https.  Soon as I do a hard refresh with clear cache - the session updates and I'm logged in.  If I redirect to say /home instead of back to the "/" - logged in.  But returning to "/" from "/home" without hard refresh - same thing.  have to hard refresh again

Comment: You may be on to something tho - I disabled the redirect on the http site so I could test if this was in someway related.  Logged in via the http site and everything worked.

Comment: Interesting, it might help to show your routes and the redirection bits of your login controller

Comment: Will update shortly - but it may require some explaining - removed the forcedHttps from my AppServiceProvider.  On http - works perfectly.  On https - is where I'm failing.

Comment: Yeah, Id bet its related to cookies and them not being sent in that case for some reason. Thats definitely where Id start digging anyway.

Comment: For curiosity, why sessions if frontend is in Vue? Why not use JWT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was a web service worker I had forgotten I had on the HTTPS site.  Best guess is its not recognizing that the site is online and is reloading information from the cache as it is a PWA application meant to be used on the internal network of the company.  Once I removed the service worker - all was good.  Never saw this action from it before so will investigate that further, but I have at least found the main error.

Closing this question and shout out to @Wesley Smith for getting my brain working.